# Confused in using the salvage value in Rate of Return.

Tags: economics

I am trying to solve a rate of return question from the book Engineering Economics by R. Paneerselvam. In that particular problem I am given a salvage value along with other factors. Following are the factors:

i)  Initial cost

ii) Annual incremental revenue

iii) Life

iv) Life-end Salvage value (Rs.)

Now when salvage value is  not given we use the following formula:

$PW_n(i) = -P + A(P/A,i,n)$

Now how will this formula be modified when salvage value is also added? I mean what factor will be introduced alongside the Salvage value?

Comment: I´ve noticed that I didn´t discounted the sum of the annuities. I´ve made an edit of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the present value of the salvage value ($S$)  you discount the  value of the salvage $n$ times. Therefore the whole formula is

$$PV_n(i)=-P+A\cdot \frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i\cdot (1+i)^n}+\frac{S}{(1+i)^n}$$

Comment: won't we use S(F/P) instead of S(P/F)?

Comment: I don´t know the meaning of S(F/P) or S(P/F). It would be nice if you show what formula it is. Beside this, I´m 100% sure that the Formula I´ve written is right. It is the present value if you have initial cost, n annuities and a salvage.

Comment: the one you used in the formula is P/F. $S(F/P) = S(1+i)^n$

Comment: @AhmadQayyum We get the salvage value (S) after $n$ periods. To obtain the present value we have  to discount it $n$ times.